# Surface construction with point cloud 3D model in opengl

Tags: opengl, 3d, mesh, point-clouds, surface

I am working on a project to construct a 3D model of a shoe.

I have now created the point cloud of the shoe but have no idea how to construct the surface of it.

I've heard about using bezier surface or Delaunay triangulation and tried using CGAL too, but all of this seemed too complicated.

Is there any simpler way to just use opengl to construct a mesh or surface of some kind?

Much thanks.

Comment: CG is complicated. Don't know what you were expecting.

Comment: OpenGL is just drawing things. OpenGL does not know what a "mesh" is or how the topology of a model relates to its vertices. All it knows are points, lines and triangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have now created the point cloud of the shoe but have no idea how to construct the surface of it.

How did you construct the point cloud? 3D scan? If so, there are a lot of programs specifically designed for surface reconstruction from point clouds. I suggest you use those. A very simple method is creating an implicit surface from the point cloud, where each point contributes a 1/r^n field, which gives rise to a field of sums and you can place the surface at some threshold using marching cubes or marching triangles algorithm.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9l2vBy21x6oTy1UMVFTSFRjWWs/view?usp=sharing

I took pictures with a perceptual camera of the four sides of a shoe, shown above.

Comment: Now I'll have to integrate it together to form a complete shoe model, and I think creating a surface to connect the four point clouds will be a decent way of doing it.

Comment: @SodaGuns: Well, OpenGL is a system for *drawing* stuff. It doesn't help with things like surface reconstruction. What you need is a program like Skanect, ReconstructMe. I'm a bit out of the loop on reconstruction algorithms; you may find source code on the websites of INRIA / LORIA which did a lot of research on the topic some 10 years ago. Also this paper might be helpfull: http://lgg.epfl.ch/reconstar_data/reconstar_eg14.pdf – the most simple approach is the one I outlined already: Build a scalar field from the points and use some algorithm like marching cubes or marching tetrahedra.